# Different Means for Same Data R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to get the means of three sections of a particular column.  As seen below, I've separated the data into the three sections by row and found the means

```
> x<-mydata[1:50,3]
> mean(x)
[1] 1.462
> za<-mydata[51:100,3]
> mean(za)
[1] 4.26
> ch<-mydata[101:150,3]
> mean(ch)
[1] 5.552
```

I tried to put this into one statement, but the means come out different than those of the separate statements.

```
mydata[c(mean(1:50), mean(51:100), mean(101:150)), 3]
[1] 1.9 4.3 5.7
```

The second mean seems rounded to the tenths place compared to the original mean, but the same cannot be said for the other two means.  Is there something happening within the concatenate function that would change the means?

Comment: Can you attach the underlying data?

Comment: You're method is invalid syntax. Consider `(1:50)[mean(1:50)]` The mean is 25.5. The call returns 25. So within `[` the value is truncated, returning the 25 value in the vector `1:50`. Maybe clearer with `letters[mean(1:50)]` which returns "y". From the help file in `?"["`, it says *Numeric values are coerced to integer as by as.integer (and hence truncated towards zero).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
c(mean(mydata[1:50,3]), mean(mydata[51:100,3], mean(mydata[101:150,3])
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Any chance you know why mine was giving similar but different answers?

Comment: You were doing the mean of the indexes instead of getting the numbers by indexing and then doing the mean. The order of calls alters the result

Answer (score 0):

`mean(1:50)` will give you the mean of the integer sequence starting at 1 and ending at 50.

```
mydata[c(mean(1:50), mean(51:100), mean(101:150)), 3]
```

will give you the values in `mydata` at row indices `mean(1:50)`, `mean(51:100)` and `mean(101:50)`, and column index 3.

```
c( mean(mydata[1:50, 3]), mean(mydata[51:100, 3]), mean(mydata[101:150, 3]) )
```

should give you the expected result.

A couple of different solutions to the same problem:

```
sapply(split(mydata[, 3], ceiling(seq_along(mydata)/50)), mean)

sapply(split(mydata[, 3], rep(1:3, each=50)), mean)
```